# Firefox 4 toolbar overlay

Tags: firefox, xul

i'm trying to make an own firefox toolbar and I have problem with overlay.
So i already setup my environment (i can see my extension in FF extensions manager), now I'm trying to add new overlay.

**chrome.manifest**

```
content sandbox chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://sandbox/content/overlay.xul
```

**overlay.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<overlay
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<toolbox id="browser-toolbox">
  <toolbar id="findfile_toolbar">
    <label control="findfile_filename" value="Search for files named:"/>
    <textbox id="findfile_filename"/>
    <label control="findfile_dir" value="Directory:"/>
    <textbox id="findfile_dir"/>
    <button label="Browse..."/>
  </toolbar>
</toolbox>

</overlay>
```

When i restart my FF i don't see result, where is the problem?

Comment: The overlay seems fine. I suggest that you open Error Console and look for warnings - maybe your chrome namespace didn't register correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that your toolbox element ID is "browser-toolbox" not **navigator-toolbox**. In Firefox, if you want to add a toolbar to the UI, you need to use "navigator-toolbox" as the toolbox ID.

You can read more about toolbar development at [the Born Geek toolbar tutorial](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/).